# Casting a constant to a pointer increases .data size by 1000 bytes

Tags: c, arduino, avr, arduino-uno, avr-gcc

I'm at a total loss with this one, I don't even know what to include in my question.

When I cast a constant to a pointer my (.data + .bss + .noinit) section grows by 1K, exceeding the ATmega328P's capacity.

```c
PK16_TABLE_T* pk16_find_table_by_index(PK16_T* p_pkg, SIZE_T index)
{
    SIZE_T offset;
    PK16_TABLE_T* p_table;

    p_table = (PK16_TABLE_T*) 0;

    return p_table;
}
```

If I cast a pointer then the data size stays the same, not growing by 1K:

```c
PK16_TABLE_T* pk16_find_table_by_index(PK16_T* p_pkg, SIZE_T index)
{
    SIZE_T offset;
    PK16_TABLE_T* p_table;

    p_table = (PK16_TABLE_T*) &offset;

    return p_table;
}
```

Where do I even start debugging this? What else do you need to see to be able to understand what might be happening?

```c
/** A single entry in a PK16 package. */
typedef struct {
    /** Null-terminated string representing the path of this entry. */
    CHAR_T path[PK16_MAX_PATH_LEN];
    /** Index into the package data buffer of the start of this entry's data. */
    U16_T head;
    /** Length in bytes of this entry's data in the data buffer. */
    U16_T len;
    /** CRC32 of this entry's path + data. */
    U32_T crc;
} PK16_TABLE_T;
```

Comment: Have you considered `return 0;`? You don’t need the variable.

Comment: What about `p_table = 0;` or `p_table = NULL;`?

Comment: Not related to your issue but hello dangling pointer to a local variable. `p_table = (PK16_TABLE_T*) &offset;`

Comment: @RetiredNinja that was just to demonstrate that casting a pointer doesn't cause the problem ;)

Comment: @MattMurphy Figured, but you never know. :)

Comment: I suppose you are building with optimization for size (`-Os`) and only change the single line of code between builds?

Comment: Either example is gibberish. Why would you set the pointer either to a null pointer or to the address of a local variable? Also the latter is likely causing a strict aliasing violation further down the line as well. Also do you know which programming language you are using? I find that it helps. Arduino is most often using C++, with slightly different rules for null pointers and strict aliasing both, compared to C.

Comment: @Lundin I obviously removed all of the code that isn’t relevant to the example…

Comment: @nielsen I'm not using any optimizations, but yes this is the only change between builds. It apparently decides the difference between whether a particular static array is relevant or not.

Comment: `p_table = (PK16_TABLE_T*) &offset;` can never be correct no matter how much other code you put in that function. It is in fact a classic beginner bug that everyone writes at one point when still learning how variable scope and the stack works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone in the comments helped me solve this, but they deleted their comment for some reason.

**I used `readelf` to analyze what symbol got added.**

It's the CRC32 polynomial table! I don't know why the constant cast decides whether that symbol gets included, but that's the answer.